# how can i resolve my problem with sql request in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a problem with my sql request in my php. I try to use the "query" but when I do a "fetch" I get an error. I know this error is because of my sql request but I can't find the problem.

my php code :

```
            $host = 'localhost';
            $dbName = 'appliderencontre';
            $username = 'root';
            $pswd = '';

            try
            {
                $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" .$host .";dbName=" . $dbName, $username, $pswd);
                //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } 
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e;
            }

            $requete = "SELECT pseudo FROM user";
            $reponse = $db-> query($requete);

             while($donnee = $reponse->fetch()){
                 echo $donnee['pseudo'];
             }

            $reponse ->closeCursor();
```

And that is my error :

[image]

I need your help, i can't find anything for helping me.

Thanks a lot !

(Sorry for my english, i'm a begginer).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Remove the comment marks from `//$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` so it looks like `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and then run the code again. It should give you a better error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code :

```
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" .$host .";dbName=" . $dbName, $username, $pswd);
```

to

```
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" .$host .";dbname=" . $dbName, $username, $pswd);
```

because `dbname` must be lower-case.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run this code and use **PDO::FETCH_OBJ** in the fetch function.

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = '';
    $dbname = "appliderencontre";

    try {
        $dns = "mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbname.";charset=utf8";
        $pdo = new PDO($dns, $user, $password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "PDOError: " . $e->getMessage()." In ".__FILE__;
    }
    $query = 'SELECT pseudo FROM user';
    $query = $pdo->query($query);
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo $row->pseudo;
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: What have you changed, and why? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: How can you be sure it will definitely work? Explain to everyone what you changed, and why it was necessary. See [answer] for more guidance on writing useful answers (rather than just encouraging a cargo-cult copy-and-paste guesswork culture). P.S. Please also note the correct spelling of "definitely".

Comment: @NicoHaase please check my updated answer

Comment: You should still explain _why_ that's necessary compared to the OP's code.